# Добавлять несколько разных ссылок в лист

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Объявление ArrayList в методе

```
            viewHolder.photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullScreenViewActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("position", position);
                            images.add(0, "https://" + StringUtil.URLADS_THUMBLER_IMAGE + images.get(position));
                            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("items_to_parse", (ArrayList<String>) images);
                            context.startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });
```

На данный момент пробовал добавлять **ссылку на изображение** таким образом.

```
images.add(0, "https://" + StringUtil.URLADS_THUMBLER_IMAGE + images.get(position));
```

Но выбивает ошибку:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0

*Но мне необходимо добавлять несколько ссылок*, причём они не фиксированные - каждый раз разные (их вводят пользователи).

Comment: можете объяснить понятнее, что вам надо?

Comment: @МаксимКузнецов по-моему название вопроса говорит само за себя, разве нет?

Comment: private void yourMethod(){List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();}
объявление в методе

Comment: Не понятна суть вопроса.

Comment: ты объявил список и тут же у него берешь string, поэтому и ошибка

Comment: setOnClickListener и зачем 2 раза так делать?

Comment: Как так-то?  `images.add(0, "https://" + StringUtil.URLADS_THUMBLER_IMAGE + images.get(position));`
Вы берете 1 элемент из только что объявленного списка, кроме того еще одновременно с этим пытаетесь положить в него элемент из него же пустого, лол, ошибка из-за этого и возникает

Comment: зачем объявлять List и делать Cast, если можно объявить ArrayList?

Comment: @georgehardcore я понимаю что неправильно, но пытаюсь как то добавить возможность добавлять(add) n-ое кол-во ссылок. Ну так я себе это представляю по крайней мере.

Comment: @georgehardcore Cast? делаю как вижу в примерах( подскажите как сделать лучше, и главное почему так.

Comment: У вас images поле в классе?

Comment: Код адаптера хотя бы прикрепите

Comment: @georgehardcore нет.
Если прикреплю это будет только хуже)
Потому как он на данный момент используется в другом участке кода. Где по открытию фотографии есть возможность её листать.
Я в другом фрагменте решил использовать такое же, и поэтому обращаюсь в intente к этой же активити и собственно к этому адаптеру, но затрудняюсь их правильно связать между собой, чтоб работало как и там(

Comment: @Inkognito, images является полем класса?

Comment: @georgehardcore не знаю как ответить вам) делал по примеру другого фрагмента ...)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("items_to_parse", new ArrayList<>());
```

Можете задать размер или заполнить сразу, к примеру так:

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("items_to_parse", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Первый", "Второй", "Третий")));
```

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня размер может быть каждый раз. Зависит от того сколько пользователь добавит фотографий в список.